# Naming suffix -氏 (-し) used by an otaku character in anime

Tags: slang, names, suffixes, anime

In the anime *Steins;Gate 0*, the male otaku-character Hashida Itaru calls female characters with suffix -し.

For example:

> Makise Kurisu - Makise-shi
>   Kiryuu Moeka - Kiryuu-shi

What does this suffix mean? Is it an otaku version of -さん?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it otaku version of -さん?

Yes...sort of.

Originally, -氏【し】 is a honorific and highly formal name suffix used to refer to someone with high social status. There are several existing questions regarding its non-otaku, "proper" usage on this site:

- [What criteria decides whether to print 「氏」 or 「さん」 at the end of a person's name in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21478/5010)
- [What does 氏 mean after a name, how is it different from さん or 様?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2482/5010)
- [Is the honorific postfix -氏{し} usually used towards men?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49051/5010)

So basically 氏 is not something you will hear in casual situations. However, 氏 is now also known as a stereotyped, funny, otaku-ish way of addressing people. It is believed by some that hardcore otaku people call one another using -氏 (or even -[殿]{どの}) instead of -さん. In reality, very few real otaku speak like this on a daily basis, so you can think of it as part of the role language of stereotyped hardcore otaku like Hashida. Another famous user of 氏 in fiction is [Saori Makishima](http://oreimo.wikia.com/wiki/Saori_Makishima).

Oh, 氏 is a gender-neutral suffix also among otaku. If you thought Hashida uses 氏 only towards girls, that's simply because the only male friend of Hashida in the story is Rintaro Okabe. Okabe and Hashida are very close friends, and Hashida doesn't need any name suffix to address Okabe.

Comment: _"the only male friend of Hashida in the story is Rintaro Okabe"_

Have you forgotten that Lukako is a guy? :-)  I can't immediately come with an instance of Daru referring to him, though I would expect -shi.

Comment: @VladimírČunát Yes, my memory is vague but perhaps Daru was using ルカ氏. But Luka is a type of character who may well be called even ルカちゃん, so this fact  doesn't prove 氏 is gender-neutral.

Comment: Right, it wouldn't be a very strong argument with a character whose gender is kind-of ambiguous.   Especially with events like Daru joking about the Mayuri+Luka pair being "so yuri" (SG1, even though being perfectly aware of the genders).