# What is the meaning of 氏談

Tags: meaning

I have 2 questions related to the following sentence :

> のみならず、新聞記者を相手に、ほらを吹いたり、自分の話が何々氏談などとして、新聞に載せられたりすることは、おとなげないとは思いながら、誰しも悪い気持はしないものである。

1. How to use 何々 as a pronoun ? What role does it play in this sentence ?
2. What's the meaning of 氏談 ? Is it a noun ? I can't find any clear entry about it on Google or on jisho.org.

Comment: @A.Ellett How do you pronounce it ?

Comment: I'm not native speaker but I would pronounce it as, なになにしだん

Comment: For pronunciation help, this entire story (Edogawa Rampo’s Ni Sen Douka) is read here -> https://youtu.be/Bsfp4LqpnRo
[二銭銅貨 - 乱歩江戸川]

Comment: Thank you, that is useful, even though the voice seems automatized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. How to use 何々 as a pronoun ? What role does it play in this sentence?

[何々]{なになに} is a placeholder for an unknown word, like "so-and-so" or "blah-blah".

> 2. What's the meaning of 氏談 ? Is it a noun ? I can't find any clear entry about it on Google or on jisho.org.

～[氏]{し} is a suffix "Mr/Ms~~". XX[談]{だん} is another suffix meaning "talked by XX" "XX said".

> 自分の話が何々氏談などとして、新聞に載せられたりする...

One's story is put in the newspaper, as "Mr. So-and-so said"...

Comment: What's the difference between ~氏 and ~さん as a suffix for Mr./Mrs. ?

Comment: @blaoi: That exact question is answered here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43091/what-is-the-difference-between-%e6%b0%8f-and-%e3%81%95%e3%82%93