# Is the honorific postfix -氏{し} usually used towards men?

Tags: honorifics

Is using the honorific postfix -氏{し} usaged biased towards men or is it equally appropriate to be used for women as well?

Building from this excellent answer about honorifics: [What does 氏 mean after a name, how is it different from さん or 様?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/what-does-%E6%B0%8F-mean-after-a-name-how-is-it-different-from-%E3%81%95%E3%82%93-or-%E6%A7%98)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There used to be a clear bias toward men, but today you can safely use 氏 for women as well. If you read articles written in the Meiji or Taisho period, you'll probably see 氏 used for men and 女史 for women with a high social status. I found an example [here](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/1971913/e/d2591fe836716e927a85162415a23315). Note that horizontal sentences were written from right to left in those days.

Today, 女史 has almost fallen out of use, and 氏 has become almost completely gender-neutral.

That said, 氏 tends to be preferred for a person with a higher social status. You may find a recent interview article where 氏 is used for a male CEO and さん is used for his wife and daughters.

Here's a relevant explanation on Wikipedia (From [敬称](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%AC%E7%A7%B0)):

> #### 氏（し）
>
> 肩書きを別にして紹介する時に使用し、一般的に話し言葉ではあまり使われず、書き言葉または報告や報道といった改まった場面で用いる。**主として男性に用いることが多かったが、現在では女性に対して用いることも多い**。
>
> #### 女史（じょし）
>
> 社会的な地位が高い女性に対して用いる（本来は男性に用いる「氏」に対応した女性用の敬称だったが、男性と対等な女性とは、かつてはすべて社会的に高い地位を獲得した女性だけだった）。現在では古風な表現。場合によってはやや揶揄的に用いられる。

Comment: Interesting bit of history. I only ever hear/read it in news reports, and even then only with respect to people who don't have another title that can be appended to their name. I get the (not necessarily justified) impression that it serves as a replacement for さん in contexts where the latter would sound to casual but no other appropriate title is available.

Comment: These 氏 and 女史 were reassigned or created to translate Mr. and Ms. in English.